# Why is the mongo ruby driver adding a _id key to data hash after the first insert?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am trying to insert this hash into my database:

```
a = {"name" => "Apple"}
```

So I connect using IRB.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'mongo'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> include Mongo
=> Object
irb(main):003:0> client =  MongoClient.new("localhost",27017).db("sample").collection("stack")
=> #<Mongo::Collection:0x9ee5c74 @name="stack", @db=#<Mongo::DB:0x9ee5ee0 @name="sample", @connection
```

Now this is where I run into an issue:

```
irb(main):004:0> client.count
=> 0
irb(main):005:0> a = {"name" => "Apples"}
=> {"name"=>"Apples"}
```

Works fine so far. Insert was successful.

```
> db.stack.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("525ee9d79fd1b325a4000001"), "name" : "Apples" }
```

Works on the ruby side:

```
irb(main):005:0> a = {"name" => "Apples"}
=> {"name"=>"Apples"}
irb(main):006:0> client.insert(a)
=> BSON::ObjectId('525ee9d79fd1b325a4000001')
```

**Here is where the error occurs, if I try to add the same hash again**

```
irb(main):007:0> client.insert(a)
Mongo::OperationFailure: 11000: E11000 duplicate key error index: sample.stack.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('525ee9d79fd1b325a4000001') }
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/networking.rb:103:in `send_message_with_gle'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/collection.rb:1121:in `block in send_insert_message'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/logging.rb:55:in `block in instrument'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/logging.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/logging.rb:54:in `instrument'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/collection.rb:1119:in `send_insert_message'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/collection.rb:1111:in `insert_batch'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/collection.rb:1169:in `insert_documents'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/collection.rb:389:in `insert'
    from (irb):7
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

**What? My Hash has changed**

```
irb(main):008:0> a
=> {"name"=>"Apples", :_id=>BSON::ObjectId('525ee9d79fd1b325a4000001')}
```

_id field has been added to it, so how will I handle batch Inserts if this is the way its going to be done?

Why is there default behavior to add the _id to my original hash, and **how do I get around it**

After some searching, it seems this is behaviour in the BSON Gem.

[http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/BSON/ObjectId.html][1]

```
+ (BSON::ObjectId, Object) create_pk(doc) 



 File 'lib/bson/types/object_id.rb', line 91

def self.create_pk(doc)
  doc.has_key?(:_id) || doc.has_key?('_id') ? doc : doc.merge!(:_id => self.new)
end
```

How would a person so things like:

```
a = {"name" => "Blue"}
2.times {client.insert(a)}
```

Comment: Can you just not re-use the hash?  What's so special about that particular instance?  I would imagine it's adding the object ID for you so it more accurately reflects the now-inserted document.

Comment: Well I mean, I could create a method, where I strip out the _id key, and then re-insert it, but it seems like a hack.

I cant add the original hash, because it gets a key added to it, which is the ObjectID of the inserted documented

Comment: Well, why are you just re-adding the same thing over and over?  Maybe there's a better way to accomplish your goal.  I've added a possible way.

Comment: I'm in the middle of figuring out how mongo driver works and from what I have learned, it makes sense to return the ObjectID, but leave my original hash intact. Similar to how *.upcase leaves original intact, but *.upcase! changes the original object. As for why add it over and over, what if I wanted to add the same has to two collections. If I wanted the objectID, I could do something like, @objectID = client.insert(sample_hash). Why not show me a way to add the same item, say , 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want it adding an ID, maybe just `dup` the object when you insert it?

```
a = { "name" => "Blue" }
2.times { client.insert(a.dup) }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the outcome I was aiming for. I tried assigning different variables, but it made no difference. It seems my ruby is lacking in certain areas.

Thanks.

Comment: This is standard behaviour for MongoDB. Once you insert an object, it is updated with the _id field so that if you modify and save it, the document is updated rather than reinserted with a new _id.